# What should I do if a repository has no release file? (Can't install via terminal)

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, ppa, repository

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) I cannot seem to install anything through terminal as it spits back the error: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

Looking at the other question, it suggests removing the ppa, which I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu'.
ERROR: '~launchpad.net' user or team does not exist.
```

Also, when I do try to install something, the original error is:

```
   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

*Please note this issue was happening before I switched to kbuntu as well*

If anyone has a solution for this, I'd greatly appreciate a helping hand, thanks!

Comment: You'll want to look at the files in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and find the one that references that particular PPA. From there you can comment out the repo, rename the file to something *not* ending in `.list`, or delete the file altogether. Once done, then you can `sudo apt update` and things should be a little bit better.

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party package sources; and all security checks are on you to perform before adding. A PPA that ended support in 2018 to me would be a reason to not add it; let alone the fact that it doesn't support *focal* or 20.04 (it didn't exist in 2018..)   Did you check https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/brackets before adding?

Comment: The equivalent command for your case would be `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/brackets`